# How do I route in Process Builder based on role hiearchy?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, role-hierarchy

We have two different groups in our company serving as admins for Salesforce.  One covers the EU and one covers North America.  I want to create a workflow rule for leads so that a lead is routed to one of these groups for conversion when a salesperson changes the lead to qualified.  In our role hierarchy we have something that looks like this:

Global Manager
|
--EU Manager
--NA Manager

All users in the EU or NA are in roles that roll up to their respective regional managers.  I would like a workflow rule that basically says, if the user is in an EU role route to the EU group and if the user is in an NA role route to the NA group.

How would I set this up in Process Builder so that the rule routes properly when someone can be anywhere in the hierarchy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot reference a User field in a criteria when creating a Lead Process. A workaround would be to create a formula field on the Lead with the following logic and have the Process look at this custom field to determine how to route.

Formula: Current User Role
Logic:

```
$User.UserRoleId
```

Good Luck!

Luis Luciani

Comment: This is good.  It gets me the user's role ID so I can at least reference it.  We have a lot of roles though.  It seems the only way to route would be to explicitly name all the potential roles.  Is that correct?  Ideally I'd like to be able to say: If this user's role equals anybody under the North America President role then true.

Comment: @Fritz, if all your roles have the string EU or NA in the role name, for example EU Manager, EU Billing, etc. Then you might be able to use $UserRole.Name combined with with text functions (BEGINS, FIND, CONTAINS, etc) in a formula field.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the user roles which have EU/NA mentioned either as a prefix or suffix in the names across all levels.

Now you can use the formula field to get the UserRole and identify which role is it using the text Contains function.

```
IF(CONTAINS($UserRole.Name,"EU"), true, false)
```

true means User belongs to the EU group
false means User belongs to the NA group